# How to convert the data type in JSON nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have a NodeJS Express Code that is simply passing data from client to my back end server in request-response format.
Now My client is expecting the dollar amounts in the JSON response as double datatype.
How do I do it dynamically.
For example below,

```
var data =   [
{
   "feeType":"Trip",
   "feeCategory":"Transaction",
   "feeAmount":0,
   "isApplicable":true,
   "isRequired":true,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"None",
   "appliedFeeAmount":0
},
{
   "feeType":"FerryFee",
   "feeCategory":"Passenger",
   "feeAmount":2,
   "isApplicable":true,
   "isRequired":false,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"None",
   "appliedFeeAmount":2
},
{
   "feeType":"WillCall",
   "feeCategory":"Service",
   "feeAmount":0,
   "isApplicable":false,
   "isRequired":false,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"Pickup",
   "appliedFeeAmount":0
},
{
   "feeType":"NotTravelling",
   "feeCategory":"Service",
   "feeAmount":0,
   "isApplicable":false,
   "isRequired":false,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"PrintAtHome",
   "appliedFeeAmount":0
},
{
   "feeType":"Pickup",
   "feeCategory":"Delivery",
   "feeAmount":0,
   "isApplicable":false,
   "isRequired":false,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"None",
   "appliedFeeAmount":0
},
{
   "feeType":"PrintAtHome",
   "feeCategory":"Delivery",
   "feeAmount":0,
   "isApplicable":false,
   "isRequired":false,
   "applicableDeliveryType":"None",
   "appliedFeeAmount":0
}
```

]

My Client is expecting as the number values with .0 or decimal numbers. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-currency-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Taki's answer is correct; just want to point out that your output is not JSON but an object, and you're not asking to change the data type, but the format. There is no "double" data type in JavaScript.

Comment: JSON doesn't have a double data type, it only has a number type, and `36.0` and `36` are identically equivalent.

Comment: What is your end goal here? There's no reason for whole numbers to be serialized as a decimal, that will just needlessly increase the transmission size when you send or receive the data. If you plan on displaying the data in some way you can simply call `toFixed()` on the number when inserting it into the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` to loop throgh the object and use `.toFixed()` to add the decimal :

```js
const data = [{
    "feeType": "Trip",
    "feeCategory": "Transaction",
    "feeAmount": 0,
    "isApplicable": true,
    "isRequired": true,
    "applicableDeliveryType": "None",
    "appliedFeeAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "feeType": "FerryFee",
    "feeCategory": "Passenger",
    "feeAmount": 2,
    "isApplicable": true,
    "isRequired": false,
    "applicableDeliveryType": "None",
    "appliedFeeAmount": 2
  }
]

const result = data.map(o => Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = typeof value.toFixed === 'function' ? value.toFixed(1) : value;
  return acc;
}, {}))
console.log(result);
```

Or `for .. in` :

```js
const data = [{
    "feeType": "Trip",
    "feeCategory": "Transaction",
    "feeAmount": 0,
    "isApplicable": true,
    "isRequired": true,
    "applicableDeliveryType": "None",
    "appliedFeeAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "feeType": "FerryFee",
    "feeCategory": "Passenger",
    "feeAmount": 2,
    "isApplicable": true,
    "isRequired": false,
    "applicableDeliveryType": "None",
    "appliedFeeAmount": 2
  }
]
const result = [];
data.forEach(o => {
  const tempObj = {};
  for (let key in o) {
    tempObj[key] = typeof o[key].toFixed === 'function' ? o[key].toFixed(1) : o[key];
  }
  result.push(tempObj);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your solution is good if the OP doesn't mind to have the values now as String rather Number.

Comment: @Dez In JS, you can't have a number with a `.0` at the end. Any numbers with zeros after the decimal will always be represented as integers. So it has to be a string.

Comment: @taki What if I have a string value in the middle of the JSON Object? Does .toFixed convert everything to decimals?

Comment: No, if you have numbers as strings, you should parse them first, `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)` and for the second example `parseFloat(data[key]).toFixed(2)`

Comment: "feeType":"FerryFee",
      "feeCategory":"Passenger",
      "feeAmount":2,
      "isApplicable":true,
      "isRequired":false,
      "applicableDeliveryType":"None",
      "appliedFeeAmount":2
   }

Comment: I have something like that and need to convert the numbers to decimal and send back the same json to client

Comment: you should've mentionned that in the question, i edited the answer to check for strings `isNaN()`

Comment: @IceMetalPunk that's why the answer to the question should be: no, it is not possible right now in JavaScript.

Comment: @taki, Thanks for the update, but it gives me an error - toFixed is not a function

Comment: @taki - I have updated my original JSON input. Please help me in converting the numbers to decimal values. THanks

Comment: Updating you question gave me a better understanding of your needs, i updated my answer to add a check for `toFixed` function since it only exists on numbers

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. May need your contact. your super hero :)